# Google Now reminders ... view/edit/create on desktop?

Tags: google-now

Is there any way to access my Google Now reminders from the desktop via browser?

Comment: There's supposedly something in the Developer channel of Google Chrome, but nothing officially announced yet. But this isn't an Android question.

Comment: For what it's worth, you might be able to go to `chrome://flags/#enable-google-now` to turn it on. Whether it works or not is unclear.